# How to sort an array of objects based on nested key using Ramda?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I start off with an object like this:

```
const myObj = {
  key1: {a: 123, b: 'some field1'},
  key2: {a: 1, b: 'some field2'},
  key3: {a: 123123, b: 'some field3'}
}
```

I convert it to an array using `R.toPairs`, resulting in:

```
[
  ["key1", {"a": 123, "b": "some field1"}], 
  ["key2", {"a": 1, "b": "some field2"}], 
  ["key3", {"a": 123123, "b": "some field3"}]
]
```

Not sure now how to sort this array on the deeper key `a`. I hear Ramda's lenses could help but not sure how. I'm also open to non-lens approaches too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A straightforward way is to compose two props:

```
R.sortBy(
    R.compose(
        R.prop('a'), R.prop(1)
    )
)
(R.toPairs(myObj))
```

See [this recipe](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook#derivative-of-rprops-for-deep-fields) if you need more nesting.

Comment: I suggest `R.nth(1)` or `R.last` in place of `R.prop(1)`.